# Doctrine limit to a number ignoring duplicate

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I'm using Symfony 3.4 and I have a request in my user repository.

I want the top 5 users based on score. So I have created my request with an order by on score column and a limit to 5 result.

```
  $query =  $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.score', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults(5)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

But I want the top 5 with taking the user with same score. For exmaple with:

User : Score

Jack : 100

Mick : 50

Joe : 10

Daniel : 25

Fred : 75

James : 100

Billy : 2

I want to return 6 result (because two user have the same score). What I want

Jack

James

Fred

Mick

Daniel

Joe

And If I have an other user with the same score than Mick, it should return 7 result.

The number of result return the top 5 best score but with all the user with this score.

How can I edit my query to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution with two request (feel free to say if you have better solution)

This is my code working but in my question I simplify the text, in reality my score has store on a user_session table, so it has more join and more condition but it can help.

First I get all the top 5 score with a distinct to group the same score.

```
$now = new \DateTime();
        $leaderScore = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->select('us.score')
            ->join('u.sessionUsers', 'us')
            ->join('us.session', 's')
            ->where(':now BETWEEN s.start_date AND s.end_date')
            ->setParameter('now', $now)
            ->setMaxResults(self::NUMBER_LEADERS_DISPLAY)
            ->distinct()
            ->orderBy('us.score', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

I save the worst score of the top 5:

```
$minScore = min($leaderScore);
```

And I make another request to get all users with a higher or egal score than $minScore

```
 $query =  $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->join('u.sessionUsers', 'us')
            ->join('us.session', 's')
            ->where(':now BETWEEN s.start_date AND s.end_date')
            ->andWhere('u.roles LIKE :role')
            ->andWhere('us.score >= :minScore')
            ->orderBy('us.score', 'DESC')
            ->setParameter('now', $now)
            ->setParameter('role', '%PLAYER%')
            ->setParameter('minScore', $minScore);
```

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a subquery selecting all the user that have the top5 score, as example:

```
$subQuery =  $this->createQueryBuilder('u1')
            ->select('DISTINCT u1.score')
            ->orderBy('u1.score', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults(5)
            ->GetDQL();

$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u2');

$query->where(
             $query->expr()->in(
                    'u2.score', $subquery))
            ->orderBy('u2.score', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

Hope this help

Comment: I think you might also need `distinct()` in the subquery. Am I correct?

Comment: How to get `$queryBuilder` in your second query ? And I'm not sur but the first query will return only the 5 first user by score and with egality it should return more. No ?

Comment: you are right @nifr : we must select the top5 elements i'll try to edit the answer

Comment: thanks @DessaugesAntoine I hope fix the mistake with my edit

Comment: hi @DessaugesAntoine I made another update for the querybuilder instance

Comment: Hi @Matteo, I have implement it on my project (cause in reality score is not in user table but between user and session) and look like it's not working ! I will make some test